# Calling a Hook only once before the component is rendered (Meteor/React/Apollo/Graphql)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo

I'm trying to create a feed of things that updates as you swipe down. My logic is that I need to fetch the required data before rendering the feed, and I will fetch new data every time I hit the *n*th element as I swipe down the page. So I thought of having a boolean state variable to detect the first render, and then I set that to false to not run the query again.

```
const Feed = (props) => {
    const [feedArray, setFeedArray] = useState([]);
    const [firstRender, setFirstRender] = useState(true);
    const FEED_QUERY = gql`
      query getFeedArray {
        getFeedArray
      }
    `;

    if (firstRender) {
      const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(FEED_QUERY);
      if (loading) return <Loading/>;
      if (error) return `Error! ${error}`;
      feedArray.push(...data.getFeedArray);
      setFirstRender(false);
    }

    return (
      <RenderredComponent />
    );
}
export default withApollo(withRouter(Feed));
```

Clearly, this results in an error (`Unexpected Error: Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement.`) as the `useQuery` hook is only called once in the if statement.

I experimented with different ways of doing this, as I require this data before my component is rendered. I tried `useEffect()` with `props.client.query()` but that wouldn't work since it allows the gql query to be run synchronously and hence only updates the DOM with the data on the second render, and I can't block the render based on the `loading` state. I can't place `useQuery()` in `useEffect()` as it throws an error as well (hook within a hook).

If I place the `useQuery` hook outside the if statement, it works but is run every render, which is unnecessary extra calls. For context - renders happen often as I scroll down due to how [React Swipeable Views](https://github.com/oliviertassinari/react-swipeable-views) works.

So to put it simply - how can I run the `useQuery` hook only once, before the component is rendered?

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

EDIT: Screenshots below to illustrate what's happening,

[image: Pic 1]
[image: Pic 2]
[image: Pic 3]

The first screenshot shows when it renders, and I print the data received to the console. I hardcoded a 5-element array to be returned on repeat for this example. Then as I swipe up, the component is being re-rendered although I do NOT need to fetch more data, but it is because the `useQuery` hook is being triggered. This is just going to keep fetching more data because the component will continually be re-rendered.

Also - I need to store my data in state because I will be adding to it, and there is no other way for my component to remember what was fetched the previous time.

EDIT2: The accepted answer works. But I had a misconception about how `useQuery` works, I should have done some logging on the server whenever the query was called. This calls the query once and only once, despite all the DOM updates. Furthermore, it adds it to my state only once, because after the first successful render the firstRender state is set to false. Not sure if this is ideal but this is what I would've done if I thought of logging the calls on my server.

```
const Feed = (props) => {
    const [feedArray, setFeedArray] = useState([]);
    const [firstRender, setFirstRender] = useState(true);
    const FEED_QUERY = gql`
      query getFeedArray {
        getFeedArray
      }
    `;

    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(FEED_QUERY);
    if (loading) return <Loading/>;
    if (error) return `Error! ${error}`;
    
    if (firstRender) {
      feedArray.push(...data.getFeedArray);
      setFirstRender(false);
    }

    return (
      <RenderredComponent />
    );
}
export default withApollo(withRouter(Feed));
```

Comment: hooks rule (no conditional hooks) broken, you can block further calls using `skip` option ... but there is no need to duplicate data from query into state

Comment: probably other problems outside of this component, not only rerendered (what reason?) but also created and removed? (rendered without `key` in swipe component?) ... no data in state needed even for `fetchMore`, see apollo pagination docs

Comment: I would say that swipeable is not for fetch more [use case], search for other virtual list rendering tool (rendered inside) [with swipe support]

Comment: @xadm I wanted to use framer-motion for page swiping but there were freezes due to state changes upon swiping (not native to framer motion, but because of some extra state changes I needed to make). See https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-pages-shmd9. Swipeable Views worked out better for me, and I will trigger more queries with the `onTransitionEnd` function.

Comment: Also for more clarity - pagination may not work well because I'm fetching the data randomly, so it's not in sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use state. Just use query data

```js
const Feed = props => {
  const FEED_QUERY = gql`
    query getFeedArray {
      getFeedArray
    }
  `;

  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(FEED_QUERY);

  if (loading) return <Loading />;
  if (error) return `Error! ${error}`;

  return <RenderredComponent data={data.getFeedArray} />;
};
export default withApollo(withRouter(Feed));
```

You can use `data` wherever you want.

**UPDATE**

If you want to use state for some reason, you can use it with `useEffect`. Add `data.getFeedArray` to the `useEffect` dependencies, so that when it is changed you can set the `feedArray` state.

```js
const Feed = props => {
  const [feedArray, setFeedArray] = useState([]);
  const FEED_QUERY = gql`
    query getFeedArray {
      getFeedArray
    }
  `;

  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(FEED_QUERY);
  useEffect(() => {
    setFeedArray([...data.getFeedArray])
  }, [data.getFeedArray])

  if (loading) return <Loading />;
  if (error) return `Error! ${error}`;

  return <RenderredComponent data={feedArray} />;
};
export default withApollo(withRouter(Feed));
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm not concerned about the data being received, I'm concerned about the fact that the query is continually being called even though I don't need it to be called on every re-render. I've updated my main post with screenshots to illustrate what exactly I mean. I need to save my query data in state because I will be adding on to it, and as such I need it to know what data was in it previously. I just need it to run once before the very first render, and then I will fetch more data in separate functions.

Comment: I've updated my answer according to your concerning.

Comment: I had to modify it to `if (data) setFeedArray([...data.getFeedArray])` and the second argument of useEffect() had to be `[data]` since `data` is null/undefined while the query is loading. I have a question though - is useQuery() only called once? When I `console.log(loading)` above the `if (loading)` statement, it returns true only upon the first render, and subsequently it's always false.